# jquery loop for making background glow

Tags: jquery, loops, jquery-animate

I am running a loop to make a background of an element glow continually.

```
function fb_glow() {
    $('#dev_fb_image').delay(4000).animate({'background-color':'#4065b4'},2000).animate({'background-color': 'white'},2000);
    fb_glow();
}

fb_glow()
```

I am looping by calling the function at the end of the function, but it is disabling the rest of the jquery below. But I guess this is not what to do. Where have I gone wrong? Is there a simpler way to make a background glow continually?

Answer (score 1):

Add and remove classes changing background-color with fadeIn, fadeOut effect.

```
// $.addClass("glow");
// $.removeClass("glow");

var glow = false;
var glowInterval = setInterval(function(){
     if(glow == true){
         glow = false;
         $('#dev_fb_image').removeClass("glow");
     }
     else {
          glow = true;
          $('#dev_fb_image').addClass("glow");
     }
},6000);
```

CSS:

```
.glow {
   background-color: green;
   transition: background-color 2s;
   -webkit-transition: background-color 2s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it takes you about 8 seconds to do one animation.

```
setInterval(
  fb_glow,
  8000 //-> or 9000 miliseconds to make sure you don't have any overlap.
);
```

`setInterval` will call fb_glow every 8000 milliseconds (or 8 seconds) making an indefinite loop.

---

Also remove `fb_glow();` inside of your `fb_glow` function.

```
function fb_glow() {
    $('#dev_fb_image').delay(4000).animate({'background-color':'#4065b4'},2000).animate({'background-color': 'white'},2000);

}
```

jQuery animations are based on `setInterval/setTimeout` which are asynchronous functions. This means that `fb_glow()` will be called instantly and won't wait for your animation to finish.

---

jQuery also provides a `.done()` function. You should try to see if it works. I've had mixed results with done. (You should not use `setInterval` for this...)

```
function fb_glow() {
    $('#dev_fb_image')
      .delay(4000)
      .animate({'background-color':'#4065b4'},2000)
      .animate({'background-color': 'white'},2000)
      .done(fb_glow);
}
```

> [done](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) Type: Function( Promise animation, Boolean jumpedToEnd ) A
>   function to be called when the animation on an element completes (its
>   Promise object is resolved). (version added: 1.8)

Comment: .done is a nice solution here but isn't only used for animation. Also have a look at $.when() event.